# How does Class Class actually represent other Classes and interfaces in java?

Tags: java, class, java.lang.class

I've been trying to understand that how the `Class Class` actually works in java but everywhere I look all it says is that its `references` represent the `Classes` and `Interfaces` in a running java application but nowhere I've managed to find that how actually it does that? Does it store the name of the `Classes` as a String property? or is it something else? Also I've seen in `Spring` applications we pass `SpringApplication.run(SomeClass.class, args)` and all people say that we are passing it because because we need to pass the name of class, If it so then why can't we just pass it as a String like this `SpringApplication.run("Name of that class", args)`?  And what is the advantage of getting the object of `Class Class` for a certain `Class` or `Interface`?

Comment: Did you try to look up the javadoc for Class? I use "google java class documentation" for this.

Comment: For object-oriented programming, it does not matter "how" something is implemented, it only matters "what" it does.  So from a pure use point of view there's no need to know what goes on inside a Class object.  Of course, if your purpose is education, that's entirely different.

Comment: @NomadMaker I've already tried the official documentation but still can't find a use case.

Comment: You can get the name of the class from a `Class` object. You can get its methods and call them (reflection), you can do a lot of things with it, which are described in plenty of documentation.

Comment: You asked "how" rather than a use-case. You should search for tutorials in that case.

Comment: @something I just wanna know how the object can be used in an application, That's why I asked what are it's advantages.

Comment: @Kayaman Can you please provide a link for the documentation?

Comment: See duplicates for more information, internet has the documentation somewhere.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you! the duplicates made it much clearer! :D